# Summarise graph with networkX

Tags: python, networkx

Let's assume I have the following graph (which represents a logistics network):

[image: DAG]

Are there built-in utils in NetworkX that could help me to summarise "recursively" the graph as follow:

While there are leaves:

- For each leaf in the graph (C & F in the initial state of the example):

  - Identify who produced the leaf and in which proportion, that is:
  - For C:

    - 10 come from A (via B) - no ambiguity
    - 5 come from A & E (via D), with an arbitrary allocation: 5 * 40 / (40 + 25) from E, and 5   * 25 / (40 + 25) from A
  - For F: ...
  - Remove the leaf

Struggling with implementing a reliable recursive approach.